# Change the value of the three_state property to true of the check box complement when the tree load is finished, in jsTree

Tags: jquery, jstree

In jsTree, I have the following use the check box complement and its three_state property I put it in
false, but I want to update the property when the data load finishes
three_state to true, check the documentation and I only find how to update the data of the tree, but not the properties of the complements.
I'm trying this but it does not work

```
    $.ajax({
                async: true,
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Perfiles/GetTreeData",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    createJSTrees(data);
                },
                error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                    alert(xhr.status);
                    alert(thrownError);
                },
                complete: function () {
                    $('#onflycheckboxes').jstree({
                       checkbox: {
                          three_state: true
                       },
                      plugins: ["themes", "types", "json_data", "ui", 
                      "checkbox", "children"]
                   })

                }
            });


  function createJSTrees(jsondata) {
            $('#onflycheckboxes').jstree({
                'core': {
                    'data': jsondata,
                    "check_callback": true
                },
                "types": {
                    "default": {
                        "icon": "fa fa-folder"
                    },
                },
                checkbox: {
                    keep_selected_style: true,
                    three_state: true
                },
                "children": [{
                    "state": { "selected": true },
                    "icon": "fa fa-file"
                }],
                plugins: ["themes", "types", "json_data", "ui", 
                      "checkbox", "children"]
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass `true` to the jstree function to get an existing instance of the tree. On this instance you can update the tree's properties.

```
$('#onflycheckboxes').jstree(true).checkbox.three_state = true;
```